# How to make Dialog's width match screen width

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-layoutparams

I want to create a `Dialog` with custom layout. I want it's `width` to be same as the phone screen's width and `height` as `WRAP_CONTENT`.

Here is what I tried:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.DialogSlideAnim);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_share);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;

        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        layoutParams.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
        layoutParams.width = width;
        layoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
```

The issue is that the `dialog` takes up only about 90% of the screen width, there is some margin on the left and right side of the `dialog`. How can I make it completely fill the width of the phone?

Comment: Set `dialog.setLayout(width,height);` for `dialog`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be helpful for you:

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_custom_dialog);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

or you can try with `style` class like this:

```
<style name="Theme_Dialog" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    ...
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">100%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">100%</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted solution is simple and working, but you can also try the below solution to achieve the requirement too.

**Step 1:** Create Subclass of Dialog class as you want to create custom dialog.

```
public class ARProgressDialog extends Dialog
{
    Activity context;
    public ARProgressDialog(Context context,int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(context,id);
        this.context=(Activity) context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.progress_dialog); // Your custom layout

        // BELOW CODE IS USED TO FIND OUT WIDTH OF ANY DEVICE 
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        // BELOW CODE IS USED TO SET WIDHT OF DIALOG 
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.dialogLinearLayout); // this is the id of your parent layout defined in progress_dialog.xml
        LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = width;
        layout.setLayoutParams(params);     
        ...// add your remaining code
    }

}
```

**Step 2**: Show dialog.

```
ARProgressDialog dialog=new ARProgressDialog(this,R.style.MyTheme);
dialog.show();
```

**Step 3**: Code of MyTheme.xml

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#00000000</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```